# How to measure dyno performance in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku

I have some problems with my rails application, hosted in Heroku.
I don't find big problem with NewRelic, maybe I have too few dyno.

How can I know that ? Is there a way to know the "occupation rate" of my dynos ?
I have tried Librato, but I have this message "there is no data for this time interval" on the Dyno loadaverage.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT 1 :
I have problem of "killing request". Sometimes, a very big request is sent. So, other requests are waiting in the queue. And I would like to find this big request.
I have alreay seen the "most time consuming" request in New Relic, but I don't find any request here.
So, I imagine a tool with the "occupation rate" of dyno per request. But I don't know if something like that exists.

Eric

Comment: NewRelic should show "queue size". If it's big, you need more dynos.

Comment: I have seen the time spent in request queuing, is it that ?

Comment: So, it's not what I want :) I edit the post to explain more